# MySQL database back up taking from one database on server A to another database on server b

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, import, export

I am trying to export all databases on server A and place into other databases ( not yet created) onto server B.

I am attempting to use MySqlBackup .NET as I am trying to create my own windows service in C# to run at a scheduled time as there is no time for someone everyday to click a button to back up the databases and export into another database.

I am kind of stumped as of now i have this:

```
public partial class BackUpService : ServiceBase
{
    System.Timers.Timer _timer = null;
    bool backUpRunning = false;
    public BackUpService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        BackUpLog.WriteEntry("Database Backup has begun.");
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer { Interval = 3600000 };
        _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Start();

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        BackUpLog.WriteEntry("Database Backup has finished.");
    }

    public void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0);
        TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(5, 0, 0);
        TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

        BackUpLog.WriteEntry("Checking if it's time to run the archive service and checking if the service is already running");


        if (backUpRunning)
            BackUpLog.WriteEntry("Service is already running");

        if ((now > start) && (now < end) && !backUpRunning)
        {
            BackUpLog.WriteEntry("Service is not already running and the time of day is valid to run the service.");
            try
            {
                backUpRunning = true;
                BackUpLog.WriteEntry("Initialising archive service");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logArchiveServiceError("The archive service failed. It will return to step 1 and try again: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                backUpRunning = false;
            }
        }

    }
    private void logArchiveServiceError(string errorMessage)
    {
        BackUpLog.WriteEntry(errorMessage, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        Emailer.SendErrorAlertEmail("Archive Service Error", errorMessage, null, null);
    }

    private void logArchiveServiceInfo(string info)
    {
        BackUpLog.WriteEntry(info, EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }

    //EXPORT DATABASES
    private void Backup()
    {
        string sqlDumpFile;
        string con ;
        MySqlBackup backup = new MySqlBackup(con);
        backup.Export(sqlDumpFile);

    }

    //IMPORT DATABASES
    private void Restore()
    {
        string sqlDumpFile;
        string con;
        MySqlBackup backup = new MySqlBackup(con);
        backup.Import(sqlDumpFile);
    }

}
```

I then need to process any errors or notifications so that they send automatic emails to a work email.

Comment: Hi I am just unsure of the process - as i am new to c# I think i understand the basic but I have not yet learned how i would best take informations from one database and export into another database on another server which will run at a set time of the day automatically. i have seen this which i think is the closest to what i need but just not 100% sure:

Comment: string constring = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=1234;database=test1;";
string file = "Y:\\backup.sql";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            mb.ExportInfo.AddCreateDatabase = true;
            mb.ExportInfo.ExportTableStructure = true;
            mb.ExportInfo.ExportRows = false;
            mb.ExportToFile(file);
        }
    }
}

Comment: For eg. It mentions a connection string is declared and points to say a  point on the c drive but i dont see why i would need that when i have been asked to simply take all the databases on one server onto another server back into databases.